# Is there an eslint rule to prevent assignment in a single line if statement?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to find if there is a non-plugin eslint rule that would allow any of the following:

```js
function(x) {
  let count = 0;
  if (doIncrement(x)) count++
  else (doDecrement(x)) count--
  if (count >=10) return "over nine";
  else return "keep counting";
}
```

But only error on this:

```js
let listOfThings = [];
if (treatAsString) listOfThings[0] = myString.trim();
else listOfThings = [...myString.split(',').map(stringPart => stringPart.trim())];


// or

let name = '';
if (hasFirstAndLAstName) name = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
else name = `${emailAddress}`;
```

In favour of using ternary assignment like so:

```js
const listOfThings = treatAsString
  ? [myString.trim()]
  : [...myString.split(',').map(stringPart => stringPart.trim())];

// or

let name = hasFirstAndLAstName ? `${firstName} ${lastName}` : emailAddress;
```

Does that rule (or a combination of rules) exist for eslint without involving a plug-in?

Comment: I highly doubt it. It's not a "code style" issue to have an assignment over anything else.

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/prefer-ternary.md is the first google hit for me. I doubt it will catch the assignments with two different targets (`listOfThings[0]`/`listOfThings`) though

Comment: Also, since JS tragically went with non-iterator `Array.prototype` methods, you are creating a superfluous array in `[...myString.split(',').map(/* ... */)]`, in both the fail and the pass cases, as `myString.split(',').map(/* ... */)` is already a new array.

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis "Also, since JS tragically went with non-iterator Array.prototype methods" - can you elaborate on that? (you are right about `[...abc]` being superfluous in this case)

Comment: @RoboRobok by defining `Array.prototype` methods like `map`, `filter`, `flatMap`, etc to eagerly return `Array` instead of an iterator, ES5 has doomed the popular chaining style to semantically bad performance. And as far as I have seen, no runtime detects these and bypasses the allocation of intermediate arrays in CURRENT_YEAR, so it's also practically bad performance for now.

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis I suppose that's only because of backwards compatibility, right? All evil in programming comes from legacy.

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis oh this is just code I found as an example, it's not great code, just lazily copy and pasted.

Comment: Certainly. And what's more legacy than the "progressively-enhanced" web.
To be fair, process has improved since then, and such things would have never made it in the platform if proposed today.  In fact, https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers and https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator are coming to save us.
But it all depends on if Google actually makes them fast in V8. Because Iterators in JS userspace today just aren't very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With using only base ESLint, you could try the [`no-restricted-syntax` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax). It is not specific but can disallow any syntax you want.

To figure out how you want to configure this rule, check:

- place your code in a tool that can generate the abstract syntax tree (AST) which will tell you *what* you want to forbid. The one I used is https://astexplorer.net/
- [the ESLint guide on selectors](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/selectors) which outlines *how* AST selectors can be used and combined. They are very similar to CSS selectors but target programming code.

With these two, here is what I came up with. This is just an example, you might want to adjust the rule further:

```
no-restricted-syntax: ["error", "IfStatement > ExpressionStatement > AssignmentExpression"]
```

This will forbid assignments in single-line `if` statements (and in `else`). Note that it *does not apply for blocks*.
Allowed

```
let x;
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    x = 4;
} else {
    x = 2;
}
```

Disallowed:

```
let x;
if (Math.random() > 0.5) x = 4;
else x = 2;
```

<sub>For reference, the selector for if statements with a block body that contains an assignment would be `IfStatement > BlockStatement > ExpressionStatement > AssignmentExpression`</sub>

This will only disallow *assignments* not variable declarations. A construct like `const x = 42;` falls under `VariableDeclaration` in AST, so `AssignmentExpression` is separate and only apply when a variable is already declared.

Try the online ESLint demo with:

```
/* eslint no-restricted-syntax: ["error", "IfStatement > ExpressionStatement > AssignmentExpression"] */

// allowed
function foo(x) {
  let count = 0;
  if (doIncrement(x)) count++
  else if (doDecrement(x)) count--
  if (count >=10) return "over nine";
  else return "keep counting";
}

// allowed
function foo() {
  const listOfThings = treatAsString
    ? [myString.trim()]
    : [...myString.split(',').map(stringPart => stringPart.trim())];
}

// allowed
function foo() {
  let name = hasFirstAndLAstName ? `${firstName} ${lastName}` : emailAddress;
}

// allowed - assignment is not in `if`
function foo() {
  let x = 1;
  x = 2;
}

// allowed - if statement with blocks
function foo() {
  let x;
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    x = 4;
  } else {
     x = 2;
  }
}

// disallowed
function foo() {
  let listOfThings = [];
  if (treatAsString) listOfThings[0] = myString.trim();
  else listOfThings = [...myString.split(',').map(stringPart => stringPart.trim())];
}

// disallowed
function foo() {
  let name = '';
  if (hasFirstAndLAstName) name = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
  else name = `${emailAddress}`;
}

// disallowed - single line `if` (even though there is no `else`)
function foo() {
  let x = 1;
  if (Math.random() > 0.5)
    x = 2;
}
```

[Direct link to online ESLint demo](https://eslint.org/demo#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)

As I said, this is just to showcase the functionality. It does not encourage you into using conditional statements (the error message just amounts to "don't use this") and might also not cover everything you want (e.g., assignment in `if` which is inside another `if`). But it is a start.

Still, you might want to look at making a custom plugin that more accurately checks for what you want and reports better errors. The `no-restricted-syntax` rule is probably *too* generic for most use cases.

Comment: I should have said it as soon as I saw this, but this is fantastic and 100% what I'm after! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a non-plugin one currently.

In fact, even plugin rules like [prefer-ternary](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/prefer-ternary.md) won't catch complex cases, such as your fail case that includes indexed field assignment vs full reassignment which I would classify as 'uber-complex'.

Comment: I've added another case I've seen 'in the wild', which isn't as complicated (it wasn't to hand at the time of writing)

Comment: **OH NO, MY POOR ATM!!!** ...yeah, the new case would most likely trip that rule, although the fix might leave you with immediate reassignment; `let name = ''; name = /* 
ternary */;`

Comment: You. I like you. Thanks for the update, I'd be willing to live the immediate reassignment.